# Eclipse Maven: What happens if I deactivate the the Maven Project Builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Since I'm having performance issues while building a workspace with lots of maven-projects I wonder if it is possible to deactivate the *Maven Project Builder*.

If I understand that right, the *Maven Project Builder* does not compile anything. Instead it refreshes the project-config from the POMs. I believe this is exactly what happens if I run "Maven -> update Project". If that is true I could deaktivate the Project Builder... Does anybody know if this is right?

Comment: Maven can compile your project! Its depends on how you configured your project in your idea, also your library dependencies configuration may break because they are configured via maven, at least they should.

Comment: In our case the mvn-command is used to compile in nightlybuild only. I still want to use the EclipseCompiler to have SyntaxChecking and to be able to start Unittests from the WorkSpace etc.

Comment: What does your Maven preferences in Eclipse look like? I've workspaces with a many maven projects and I don't experience any performance issues... For File -> Preferences -> Maven the only option I've selected is "Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories" checked, all other are unchecked... When you say "lots of maven-projects"...how many is that?

Comment: 60 projects. The preferences are configured as you described it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to track all your library dependencies from .m2 folder, so you can restore them easily, and check if there are some scripts in pom.xml that run on build, test, or deployment and see if you can reproduce them without Maven.

In addition you should check if there are other project in your system that depends on your project and vice versa via Maven.

Comment: Your answer sounds like you suggest to remove maven totally... or to keep eclipse and the poms in sync manually. This is not what I want, I want to deactivate just the Maven Project Builder and not maven completly. I believe that "Update Project" does the same what the Maven Project Builder does, so it would be redundant.